# Add eventlistener only if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to add eventlistener to a html element. But It creates js error when the element doesn't exist. The element exists only on some pages.

```
    // (A) ATTACH CLICK LISTENER ON PAGE LOAD
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
});
// (B) THE USUAL FUNCTION
function doSomething () {
  // (B1) DETACH CLICK LISTENER
  var div = document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0");
  div.removeEventListener("click", doSomething);
  // (B2) EXTRA - CHANGE THE TEXT IF YOU WANT
  div.innerHTML = "Downloading";
  // (B3) DO YOUR PROCESSING HERE
  alert("Downloading!");
  // (B4) RE-ENABLE AFTER PROCESSING IF YOU WANT
  // div.addEventListener("click", doSomething);
}
```

Basically, the function is to remove the button after it has been clicked, to avoid multiple redundant clicks.

I want the function doSomething to run only if the element `download_mp3j_0` exists.

Comment: so the problem is `document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0").addEventListener...`? or `div.removeEventListener...`? if it's teh former, you could do `document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0")?.addEventListener(...etc` that way you won't get an error - if it's the latter, then besides being impossible, you could do the same sort of thing using `?.`

Comment: I have edited the question as to what the problem is.

Comment: Btw, adding that question mark before .addEventListener also works, Can you be elaborate about the prob? Thank you

Comment: the problem is if the element doesn't exist you can't add an event listener to it

Comment: Now in some pages the code works, and in some pages it doesn't even though it has that element in that page. May be I should load this script on page load?

Comment: you should execute it on page load - oh, wait, you do - what error when it doesn't work?

Comment: It worked, I thought something in the header.php is blocking the code to run immediately. Thus I placed this code in the first line.

Answer (score 5):

**Optional chaining operator**

A simple alternative would be to use the [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator:

```
.getElementById(id)?.addEventListener(...
```

And the event handler is only attached when the element exists.

You might also use the disable attribute during downloading as this would avoid having to add and remove the existing event handler.

**See code snippet for details**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0")?.addEventListener("click", function() {

    let element = this;
    element.value = "Downloading...";
    element.disabled = true;
    element.style.cursor = "wait";

    // simulated download

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      element.value = "Download";
      element.disabled = false;
      element.style.cursor = "default";
    }, 2000);

  })
});
```

```css
#download_mp3j_0 {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
}

#download_mp3j_0:disabled {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="download_mp3j_0" value="Download">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
if (document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0")) { // Check if the element exists
    // Add event listener
}
```

So it makes :

```js
// (A) ATTACH CLICK LISTENER ON PAGE LOAD ONLY IF THE ELEMENT EXISTS
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if (document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0")) {
        document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0").addEventListener("click", doSomething);
    }
});

// (B) THE USUAL FUNCTION
function doSomething() {
    // (B1) DETACH CLICK LISTENER
    var div = document.getElementById("download_mp3j_0");
    div.removeEventListener("click", doSomething);
    // (B2) EXTRA - CHANGE THE TEXT IF YOU WANT
    div.innerHTML = "Downloading";
    // (B3) DO YOUR PROCESSING HERE
    alert("Downloading!");
    // (B4) RE-ENABLE AFTER PROCESSING IF YOU WANT
    // div.addEventListener("click", doSomething);
}
```

Comment: I should include all the above code within the if loop you have mentioned?

Comment: Unfortunately on clearing cache that didn't work. May be it was due to the previous code.

Comment: `within the if loop` - what is an "if loop"?

Comment: This code doesn't work on any page, although I can see that this should work.